# Best way to wrangle json data to remove field labels

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I am looking to try make it easier to use the Google Analytics data in Google sheets.

The outputs that I receive from the api look like :

```
    [
  {
    "dimensionValues": [
      {
        "value": "id2"
      },
      {
        "value": "(not set)"
      },
      {
        "value": "Android"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "dimensionValues": [
      {
        "value": "id1"
      },
      {
        "value": "stream name"
      },
      {
        "value": "iOS"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Whats the most efficient method to remove the field names to make  a "flatter set of arrays" similar to:

```
[["id2","(not set)","Android"], ["id1","stream name","iOS"]]
```

It feels like there should be a quick way to do this!

Comment: Hi @UKDataGeek, does the answer below work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double `map` for this one. Map the `value` to its `dimensionValues` and then map those to the array elements to get the designated output.

```js
let array = [{"dimensionValues": [{"value": "id2"},{"value": "(not set)"},{"value": "Android"}]},{"dimensionValues": [{"value": "id1"},{"value": "stream name"},{"value": "iOS"}]}]  

console.log(array.map(x => x.dimensionValues.map(y => y.value)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this Octavia.  Map is my Kryptonite... I am going to try digest it and see if I can understand how it works..

Comment: Hi @UKDataGeek, feel free to comment if you have something to clarify. But basically map just replaces the element based on what you return. In this case, the inner `x.dimensionValues` map replaces its elements with the value property. Resulting should be the areay containing the values. And the outside map now replaces the objects with these array of values. Resulting into arrays of array of values.